# How to store more than 255 characters in a custom settings field?

Tags: customsetting

In an apex class I have a custom pick list whose values are displayed depending on profile. But now I want to remove the hard-coded profile names being used in the code. For that I am creating a hierarchical custom setting but the data to be stored in the field is more than 255 characters so I am not able to do that. And as I want data to be dynamically displayed so I cannot use custom label or custom object. What can I do to solve this problem.
Please help.

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: try custom meta data

Answer (score 2):

Instead of custom settings, you can use Custom Metadata settings.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm

Custom metadata supports Text Area

**~~~UPDATE~~~**

Text Area (Long) is now available in [Custom metadata types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_about.htm&type=5).

Allows users to enter up to 131,072 characters on separate lines.

Comment: Text Area on Custom Metadata also is limited to 255 characters.

Comment: Text Area (long) is supported in Custom metadata types. @rmarq423

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but assuming you only need say 1k or 2k characters of space in total, you can add multiple 255 character fields to the custom setting called e.g. Entries0, Entries1, Entries2, Entries3 etc and join them up in code:

```
    String[] entries = entries(new String[] {
            setting.Entries0__c,
            setting.Entries1__c,
            setting.Entries2__c,
            setting.Entries3__c
            });

private String[] entries(String[] parts) {
    String[] result = new String[] {};
    for (String part : parts) {
        if (!String.isEmpty(part)) result.addAll(part.split(','));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This keeps the ability to have separate values per profile via the hierarchical custom setting mechanism.

**PS**

Another approach is to just hold the name of a static resource in the custom setting. That allows the name to be varied per profile, and a static resource can be up to 5M in size. The code then also has to query the static resource:

```
String[] entries = new String[] {};
for (StaticResource sr : [
        select Body
        from StaticResource
        where Name = :MyCustomSetting__c.getInstance().StaticResourceName__c
        ]) {
    entries.addAll(sr.Body.toString().split(','));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but  the problem with multiple fields is if later on data for the fields increases then I would have to create more field. With that I have to make changes in the code also. That is the thing I don't want. I need something that doesn't need changes in the codes afterwards even if the data changes or increases.

Comment: @RohitKhetan If you want to allow up to 5M of data, see the PS.

Comment: If I store a static resource name in the custom setting then how can I get data as a pick list value?

Comment: @RohitKhetan Use the name to query the static resource body then split the values then turn them into `SelectOption[]` in your controller and present those values via apex:selectOptions.

Comment: @ Keith C I am not getting how to store the name of static resource in the custom setting field. Can you help me with that.

Comment: @RohitKhetan You just need a text field to store the name. I've added a bit of code to the answer to show how that might then be used.

Comment: There is some error in the query as the query is not fetching the values . Can you check once the query....
select Body 
from StaticResource
where Name in: Profile_Dependency_Specification__c.getInstance().LPReasonCode

Comment: @RohitKhetan The "in" should be an "=" - see changed code.

Comment: The error it is showing here is that after getInstance(). it is asking for the field name and when I give field name it accepts but thn where should I give the static resource name.
1 more thing why are you using __c after StaticResourceName..?

Comment: @RohitKhetan The static resource name is stored in a text custom setting field and all custom setting field names end in `__c`. Can we stop this thread now - this is a Q and A site not a support forum.

Comment: Thanks for the help. and sorry for disturbing you so long.